# How can I test an object using Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm using `jest` and I want to create a test get api call. In order to do that, I need to add the data into the db. What's the proper/best way to test the data?

```
describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should return all users', async () => {
        await Users.collection.insertMany([
            {
                name: 'mike',
                age: 39
                gender: 'other
                description: 'This is a cool desc',
            },
            {
                name: 'seth',
                age: 19
                gender: 'trans
                description: 'This is another cool desc',
            },
        ]);


        const res = await request(server).get('/api/users');
        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        expect(res.body.length).toBe(2);
        expect(res.body.some((t)=> t.name === 'mike')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

// This is the test I currently have. Should I be going through every data field, i.e. name, age, gender, description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking every field. If your data is the same coming out as inserted directly in db then it's easy to just use:

```
expect(res).isEqual(seeds). // where seeds is your array to insert
```

Oftentimes though there is a disparity in the data - the fetch may add some stuff like a timestamp, an id etc. There are some tools in jest to help with that namely [arrayContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectarraycontainingarray) and [objectContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectobjectcontainingobject). You can do things like:

```
expect(res).isEqual({ 
  name: 'foo',
  id:  expect.any(String)
})
```

Here's a pretty good [blog post](https://codewithhugo.com/jest-array-object-match-contain/) explaining how to use them.